# Are yaml pipeline tasks opensource?

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking for ways to fork some of the yaml pipeline tasks and create my own modified version of them.

Is there any way to see the source code of the yaml pipeline tasks such as `NuGetCommand@2`, `VSBuild@1`, `CopyFiles@2` or `PublishBuildArtifacts@1`?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks

Comment: @PeterBons I was writing answer the same time with you. We almost answered together. Thumbs up for our synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, tasks are opensource and you can find them on the below repository inside `Tasks` folder.

> https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks

For example the `CopyFiles@2` can be located on
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/CopyFilesV2